# Get Database Table's Trigger Name

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, triggers, database-trigger

Wonder how can we get specific table's trigger name in Sybase Database.

Can Java JDBC able to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed this query via `Statement` object and execute this statement object via `statement.executeQuery()` and finally store the resultant in `ResultSet` Object

```
String query="select *
               from sysobjects
          where type ="+"'"+TR+"'";
      stmt = con.createStatement();
       ResultSet rs = 
        stmt.executeQuery(query);
```